# Execution-Plan with wrong Costs when involving index

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, database-indexes

Could anyone help me understand why postgresql missed several cost estimates.

I'm doing an experiment with 22 queries from the TPCH Benchmark [1],
To check the performance of indexes in queries.

Of 22 queries, only 5 queries were verified that the optimizer used secondary indexes.
In another experiment, the 5 queries quoted were executed in a database without the presence of indexes, in order to identify whether the execution time would increase due to the absence of indexes.

But to my surprise, the experiment without the presence of indexes in the database, was faster than using the indexes (for the 22 queries).

I would like to understand, because the total cost parameter was wrong in all cases, ie all the queries that spent the most time, indicated a lower cost - in all 5 cases, which is incorrect in my opinion.

See below, that the first line refers to query 6 that you used
Index, the cost was 3335809, lower than the cost 5255959, the same
Query 6 that did not use index.

Also see the time spent. The query that used index spent 7 minutes while without indexing took 55 seconds. This behavior extended to other cases.

My question is, why does the total cost (execution plan) incorrectly calculate the cost, for all cases where you have indexes?

```
Indexes |Query|Time Spent    |Total Cost
============================================
Sim      6    00:07:56        3335809.61
Nao      6    00:00:55        5255959.00
Sim      7    00:09:16        5847359.97
Nao      7    00:02:08        6793148.45
Sim     10    00:07:04        40743017.17
Nao     10    00:02:14        41341406.62
Sim     15    00:10:03        6431359.90
Nao     15    00:01:56        9608659.87
Sim     20    00:12:48        8412159.69
Nao     20    00:05:49        9537835.93
```

Follow query 6 and its Explain Analyze with and without indexes.

```
select
    sum(l_extendedprice * l_discount) as revenue
from
    lineitem
where
    l_shipdate >= date '1995-01-01'
    and l_shipdate < date '1995-01-01' + interval '1' year
    and l_discount between 0.09 - 0.01 and 0.09 + 0.01
    and l_quantity < 24; `     


-=--========= With INDEX  (idx_l_shipdatelineitem ) -=-=-====== 
Plano Execução: Aggregate  (cost=3335809.59..3335809.61 rows=1    width=16) (actual time=476033.847..476033.847 rows=1 loops=1)
 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on lineitem  (cost=376416.20..3330284.29 rows=2210122 width=16) (actual time=375293.183..471695.391 rows=2282333 loops=1)
       Recheck Cond: ((l_shipdate >= _1995-01-01_::date) AND    (l_shipdate < _1996-01-01 00:00:00_::timestamp without time zone))
        Filter: ((l_discount >= 0.08) AND (l_discount <= 0.10) AND (l_quantity < 24::numeric))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_l_shipdatelineitem000 (cost=0.00..375863.67 rows=17925026 width=0) (actual time=375289.456..375289.456 rows=18211743 loops=1)   
           Index Cond: ((l_shipdate >= _1995-01-01_::date) AND (l_shipdate < _1996-01-01 00:00:00_::timestamp without time zone))
Total runtime: 476034.306 ms
```

------------------ WITHOUT INDEX -------------------------------

```
Plano Execucao:Aggregate  (cost=5255958.99..5255959.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=55051.051..55051.051 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on lineitem  (cost=0.00..5250433.68 rows=2210122 width=16) (actual time=0.394..52236.276 rows=2282333 loops=1)
        Filter: ((l_shipdate >= _1995-01-01_::date) AND (l_shipdate < _1996-01-01 00:00:00_::timestamp without time zone)
        AND (l_discount >= 0.08) AND (l_discount <= 0.10) AND (l_quantity < 24::numeric))Total runtime: 55051.380
```

Due to specific issues of my research project, I am using an old version 9.0.1 (of the 2012 year),
 because I use a patch that only serves in this version.

I did not modify the default parameters, only the random_page_cost for 1, since I am using
An SSD disk, where the cost of random access is less than that of an HDD.

See below the content of the file postgresql.conf

My question is, did any of these parameters interfere with this error in cost statistics?

```
max_connections = 100 
effective_io_concurrency = 5 
#seq_page_cost = 1.0                    
random_page_cost = 1.0                  
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01                  
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005        
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025             
#effective_cache_size = 128MB
```

[1] www.tpc.org/tpch/

Comment: Why do you think the cost is  "incorrect"?

Comment: I assume OP asks why with index cost is twice as small, but takes 8 times longer then without index - right?..

Comment: please update the OP with: timestmp of last_vacuum (or autovacuum), postgres version, amount of ram and the size of effective_cache, random page scan cost and all not default settings

Comment: Dear Vao Tsun, I updated this parameters in main question, see above.

Comment: Yes "a_horse_with_no_name", this is the question: why with index cost is twice as small, but takes 8 times longer then without index. any suggestion?